# Perl - Need to put Username + Pwd into another secure file

Tags: oracle, perl, dbi

I have a php file that triggers this script when an insert happens into a database table. I need to put the username and password into another file and make it secure. It is used for a web application and are the same credentials throughout the app for all users. I am having no luck putting these credentials into another file.

I am assuming I should replace these with $orausername1", "$orapassword1 and place this into another file - can someone help with this code...

Using Oracle DB.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use MIME::Lite;


use DBI;

my $db = DBI->connect( "dbi:Oracle:DBNAME", "USER1", "TESTING2")
   or die "Couldn't connect to database: " . DBI->errstr;


my $to = 'john@abc.com';
my $from = 'ron@abc.com';
my $subject = 'New Movie Added';

etc...
```

Comment: Re "*I am having no luck putting these credentials into another file*", Where's your attempt? What problem are you having? You seem to have posted the wrong code!!!

Answer (score 3):

> *I have a php file that triggers this script when an insert happens into a database table.*

My first suggestion is to not call another script. Do whatever the Perl script is doing in PHP. This will be much faster, there's no need to spin up another process and reconnect to Oracle, and there's no need to share credentials.

> *I need to put the username and password into another file and make it secure. It is used for a web application and are the same credentials throughout the app for all users.*

1. Put all your application config stuff into a single config file, probably in JSON or some other easy to parse, language independent format.
2. Set it to be readable, but not writable, by the web server.

For example, you might have `/etc/yourapp.conf` which says:

```
{
    "database": {
        "type": "Oracle",
        "host": "the.db.hostname",
        "port": 12345,
        "user": "dbusername",
        "pass": "dbpassword",
        "name": "dbname"
    }
}
```

Then everything which makes up the app reads that file for configuration information, and everything can act consistently. In Perl use [JSON::MaybeXS](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::MaybeXS) to parse the JSON.

If you make the location of the config file overridable by an environment variable like `YOURAPPNAME_CONFIG_FILE` then you can use various different configs for testing and development.